# How to tell the difference between errors that I can handle and programmer errors in promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise

I have a problem with promises. It is extremely hard for me to differentiate between the type of error that I would want to crash from and the error I want to handle.

This is how I think I should solve these types of errors but I would like to know if it is an elegant way of doing so.

```
PromiseA //I believe that any errors thrown in this function will crash node

.catch(function( {throw custom_err(msg)})) 

//Here I can catch any rejected promises which I believe will always be 

//operational errors and then I can flag them as such.

//The error is then thrown to the final catch which handles it appropriately


.then(function() { return Function1().catch(throw custom_err(msg)); })

//Now if an error is thrown by Function1 inside a then statement it will 
//fall down the chain. It will then be caught by the final catch and it will not be flagged 
//as operational. My final catch will throw it and crash node which I desire.
//However if it is operational Function1 will reject the promise and it will be caught by
//the nested catch which then flags it appropriately and throws to the final catch

.catch(finalErrorHandler);
```

Does this solution work? Am I correct with my assumptions about the flow of rejections vs. throws?

Am I correct in assuming that if an error is thrown from a function in a library I am using (such as `Function1()`) it is most likely a programmer error?

Is this an elegant way of solving the problem? Is there a more obvious solution I am missing?

Comment: Question assumes that "programmer errors" cannot be handled. Why?

Comment: First off, errors thrown in `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers or rejected promises do NOT crash node.js.  So, that whole part of your question is just wrong.  All exceptions in the promise infrastructure are turned into rejected promises.  You should always handle potential rejections on a promise so you, the programmer of your server, can decide what should happen upon that error.

Comment: Second, you can't blindly assume anything about some random function.  Read the doc for that function, look at the code.  Determine how it handles errors and what it returns or throws.  Design your code based on what the library function does.  It's not good to guess here.  You need to know how something you call behaves in error conditions (returned error value, rejected promise, synchronously thrown exception, etc...).  You need to know so you can design for it.  If you don't know, then find out.  Read the doc, look at the code, simulate error conditions and test.  You have to know.

Comment: `.catch(throw custom_err(msg)); })` is NEVER correct.  You pass `.catch()` a function reference.  That's all you pass it.  Here you're not passing it anything as you're throwing synchronously.

Comment: Woops! You're right that was a silly mistake. I have node set so that it crashes on unhandled promise rejections. However what I am talking about is programmer errors such as undefined variables or functions, these are what I'm trying to catch. Say something stupid happens like a node module was deleted or corrupted and when I try to use `Function1` node throws an error. This will be swallowed by the last catch unless I have a system for differentiating thrown errors and rejected promises.

Comment: I would love it if there's  a  simple way to look at the error and know whether or not I should crash, this is what I would like to do for anything undefined, or when I try to use a function that doesn't exist. Perhaps I'm being too broad? I don't want to have to look at every single error and check whether it's a programmer error like the ones I mentioned above or a problem with a database not connecting, or aborting in the middle of a connection or any number of things. So my thought was that thrown errors are bad and rejected promises mean I should just send a database error.

Comment: Basically there are so many error codes to handle it would be inelegant to look at all of them. Perhaps there's a simpler way of  it or maybe I'm just lazy. But so far all the libraries I have don't document every single type of error. An example for how you would handle this would be great as an answer.